# How can I open an XML file with the built-in XML editor in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, rss

I am learning how to make Android applications from HEAD FIRST ANDROID. In one chapter we are making an application which will show the NASA DAILY IMAGE on an Android phone. We are using RSS feeds in it. The book says:

```
Go to "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss".  
Save the page locally as .XML file.  
Open it with Eclipse. Then this file will be opened by Eclipse's built-in XML file editor, which looks something like this:
```

[image: xml editor image]

But when the page is saved as `.XML` and it is opened with Eclipse, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

How do I open an `.XML` file in the required format as shown in the first image?

Comment: Fascinating. It looks like it was detected as HTML because of its root element and you're in the HTML Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open your XML file with Eclipse XML Editor :

1. Start Eclipse
2. Expand your project folder in `Project Explorer` window
3. Copy/paste the XML file you have on your disk into your project
   folder within Eclipse.
4. Then, in Eclipse, right-click the XML file
5. Choose `Open With --> XML Editor`

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse probably does not have the XML editing tools installed - there are several different Eclipse downloads and some of them don't include these tools.

You can install the XML tools by going to `Help > Install New Software` work with your Eclipse install site and find the `Eclipse XML Editors and Tools` in the `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` section. You might want some of the other Web tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there is a built-in editor. You need to trick something to open it. I have gone through suggestions given by other people, but none of them works well. Instead of installing a new Eclipse XML editor, do this:

1. Download NASA RSS file from http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss .
2. Convert extension to XML
3. In Eclipse, *File* -> *Open File...* (See outline for hierarchical display)
4. You can do editing on XML display by right-click -> *Preferences*.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>